# Having trouble installing MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, terminal, installation

I am trying to set up MongoDB on my local machine. I have attached some screenshots below. So I can run some of the MongoDB executable files from my terminal, but after I run ./mongod I can't call mongo as a command in the terminal. The commands git and node both work, but when I use the command mongo I get nothing.

I have the mongoDB folder with everything in it on my desktop right now and I am pretty sure that is not where it needs to be. Can anyone shed some light on the issues I might be having.

As a side note, I have MAMP installed on my localhost. Not sure if that is causing issues.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1bq8.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJI83.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you downloaded MongoDB, not installed it from brew Mac OS does not understand that `mongo` should be in your app path and when you type:

```
> mongo
```

It only searches your app path not your directory where the `mongo` binary actually is.

You can install via homebrew, which is the recommended way: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

You can also add that directory to your PATH like so:

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/path/to/mongo
```